# Xcode: CoreData generated property is "double" instead of "NSNumber"

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm having a problem with CoreData:
The data model has multiple fields with the type of `Double`:

[image: field1]
[image: field2]

So, I expect the generated CoreData properties to be of the same type, however, they're not:

```
@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *amount;
@property (nonatomic) double iccsMaterialAmountIfDifferentThanPlanItem;
```

What is the root cause of such behavior, is it an error and how to fix it if it is?

Comment: Set checkmark in `use scalar type` in data model inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the default behavior of Xcode auto generated classes, you can change it selecting `Use scalar type` on the attribute:

From the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/modeling_data/configuring_attributes):

> Use Scalar Type Optionally, for some types, choose between scalar and
>   non-scalar representations during code generation. For a Double,
>   selecting the Use Scalar checkbox produces a Double, while leaving it
>   unselected produces an NSNumber. For the full list of types, including
>   scalar variants, see NSAttributeType.

Answer (score 0):

In our experience the numeric Model and plist data types are meaningless.  They are all NSNumber.  Within your code you must read these as NSNumber and then do conversions to int, double, float or string.  At least in Objective C.

Here is an example of a number to string conversion:

```
+ (NSString *) numberToString:(NSNumber *)dbNumberIn{

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
    formatter.formatWidth = 5;
    formatter.paddingCharacter = @"   ";
    formatter.maximumIntegerDigits  = 6;
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2;
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
    formatter.usesSignificantDigits = NO;
    formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;
    formatter.groupingSeparator = @",";
    formatter.decimalSeparator = @".";

    NSString *stringFieldOut = [formatter stringFromNumber:dbNumberIn];

    return stringFieldOut;
}
```